# Convergence of the difference of two simple harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I usually prove the convergence of the following series by use of Taylor's expansion but I would like to come up with an easier proof to be able to teach to students *who did not take Taylor* yet.

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\left[\sin\left(1 \over k\right) - {1 \over k}\right]$$

Comment: It's not easy, because the Taylor series is the only way (other than using some complicated trigonometric formula maybe) to get an estimate of $\sin x$ in terms of $x$. Otherwise, we would be stuck with obvious approximations like $\sin x \leq 1$ or things like that. The first preliminary to getting these kind of approximations is the Taylor series.  Think how can get the $\frac{1}{k}$ out, and you will realize that you can't, unless you use Taylor.

Comment: I totally agree with астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг 's and I should be very interested too by an easier proof. Cheers.

Comment: Such a shame , I hope my memory is not failing me but before I learned about Taylor I recall using some mathematical manipulation to get the 1/k out and just finding the limit at infinity , by that you can find that it's limit is proportional to 1/n^3  and thus then do a limit comparison test of the sequence's nth term and the above p-series

Comment: [Abramowitz & Stegun](http://www.nrbook.com/abramowitz_and_stegun_html/page_75.htm) has some $\sin\left(x\right)$ inequalities. I don't know whether they are useful to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$\sin'(x)
= \cos(x)
$,
$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t) dt
$.

Since,
for $0 \le x \le \pi/2,
0 \le \cos(x) \le 1$,
$\sin(x)
\le\int_0^x 1 dt
\le x
$.

Since
$\cos'(x)
= -\sin(x)
$,
$\cos(x)-1
= \int_0^x -\sin(t) dt
$
or
$\cos(x)
= 1-\int_0^x \sin(t) dt
$.
Since
$\sin(t) \le t$,
$\cos(x)
\ge 1-\int_0^x t dt
=1-x^2/2
$.

Going back,
$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t) dt
\ge\int_0^x (1-t^2/2) dt
=x-x^3/6
$.

Putting $x = 1/k$,
this gives
$\frac1{k}-\frac1{6k^3}
\le \sin(\frac1{k})
\le \frac1{k}
$,
which is enough to show convergence.

Two notes:

First,
by iterating this process,
we can get the power series
for $\sin$ and $\cos$
by induction.

Second,
this is not original with me.
I found it in
"100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics (Dover Books on Mathematics)"
by Heinrich Dorrie,
a book I highly recommend.
It is $15.95 on Amazon.

What are you waiting for?
Go get it!

Answer (score 2):

You may prove through convexity that over the interval $(0,\pi)$ we have
$$ x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)\leq \sin x \leq x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
(notice that the RHS of $(1)$ is just a "partial Weierstrass product" for the sine function) hence it follows that
$$\frac{1}{\pi^2 k^3}\leq  \frac{1}{k}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\leq \frac{1}{6 k^3}\tag{2} $$
and
$$ \frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}\leq \sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)\leq\frac{\zeta(3)}{6}.\tag{3} $$

---

Now the extreme overkill. By using the inverse Laplace transform we have:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\sin\frac{1}{k}\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^s-1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}s^{2n}}{(2n+1)!(2n)!}\,ds \tag{4}$$
and the integral in the RHS of $(4)$ is clearly converging.